# MariaDB: Cannot create view using UNION ALL

Tags: sql, view, mariadb

I'm trying to create an MYSQL view, which contains UNION ALL, but i have got an error: 
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL",
the statement is like:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS (
            SELECT COL_1, COL_2
            FROM tbl_1
            INNER JOIN tbl_2 ON ...

            UNION ALL

            SELECT COL_1, COL_2
            FROM tbl_1
            INNER JOIN tbl_3 ON ...
)
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: lose the brackets

Comment: Pls provide the exact sql statement. There may be sg wrong with your on clause.

Comment: The brackets are a known bug in MySQL that was fixed in v8.0. Question is if this issue is present in mariadb as well.

Comment: Oh!
Thanks a lot, the error was just in the brackets :)